# How should I read the sep='T' from the FormatISOCombined(self, sep='T') function documentation from wxPython?

Tags: wxpython

Let's say I have this portion of code:

```
import wx

now = wx.DateTime.Now()
print (wx.DateTime.FormatISOCombined(now))
```

which gives something like

```
2021-03-02T20:47:53
```

OK. Now, instead of the T character, I want to use something else – lets' say a space, but not limited to. The documentation for [FormatISOCombined(*self, sep='T'*)](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.DateTime.html#wx.DateTime.FormatISOCombined) says:

> The sep parameter default value produces the result exactly corresponding to the ISO standard, but it can also be useful to use a space as separator if a more human-readable combined date-time representation is needed.
>
> Parameters
>
> sep (int) –

but I don't understand how should I read this.

I tried `sep = ' '` which gives `... argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'`, which seems correct, as the Parameters description explicitly says (int); however, this is confusing versus the `sep='T'` in the function definition.

I tried `sep = 0x20` which gives `... argument 2 has unexpected type 'int'`, which is why I don't understand anything anymore.

So, how should I read the documentation ?

Comment: If this question is still bothering you, I found the solution, when I ran into the same issue myself. I was surprised to discover the work around was one I wrote. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a mystery and probably either a bug or a documentation error.
The source code simply inserts the `separator` between the date and time

```
wxString FormatISOCombined(char sep = 'T') const
    { return FormatISODate() + sep + FormatISOTime(); }
```

So pragmatically, you should probably do the same, at least you won't be breaking anything.

```
print (wx.DateTime.FormatISODate(now)+" "+wx.DateTime.FormatISOTime(now))
2021-03-03 09:15:05
```

Edit 2022:

Ran into this problem myself and the answer, weirdly, is that it is expecting a `single` character `bytes` object, so the real answer is:

```
>>> print (wx.DateTime.Now().FormatISOCombined(sep=b' '))
2022-12-07 17:29:24
```